# What is the smallest $m$ such that $\mathbb{P}(\text{at least one bin with at least two balls}) \geq 1/2$?

Tags: probability

**Question:** Consider $m$ balls being thrown randomly into $n$ bins, with each ball landing in bin $i$ with probability $p_i$ for $i = 1 , \dots, n$. What is the smallest $m$ such that $\mathbb{P}(\text{at least one bin with at least two balls}) \geq 1/2$?

I have searched through many similar sounding questions but I was not able to find what I wanted (Many problems are computing expectation or computing exactly $k$ bins with $x$ number of balls etc).

Define $X_{ij}$ to be the indicator variable that ball $i$ and ball $j$ are in the same bin. Then there are $N= {n \choose 2}$ such variables.
We have
$$\mathbb{E}(X_{ij}) = \mathbb{P}(X_{ij}=1) = \sum_{i} p_i^2 =: p$$
$$\operatorname{Var}(X_{ij}) = p(1-p)$$
$$\operatorname{Cov}(X_{ij}, X_{kl}) = 0 \quad \text{where $i,j,k,l$ are distinct}$$
$$\operatorname{Cov}(X_{ij}, X_{jk})
= \mathbb{E}((X_{ij} - p)(X_{jk} - p))
= \mathbb{E}(X_{ij}X_{jk} - pX_{jk}-pX_{ij}+p^2)
= q - 2p^2 + p^2
= q - p^2$$
where $q := \mathbb{E}(X_{ij}X_{jk}) = \mathbb{P}(\text{$i, j, k$ are in the same bin}) = \sum_i p_i^3$

I have also computed the variance of $X$ to be
$$\operatorname{Var}(X) = Np(1-p) + \left[ (N^2 - N) - 6 {n \choose 4} \right] q$$

Define $X = \sum_{i < j} X_{ij}$. **Then I want find the smallest** $m$ (number of balls thrown) **such that with probability more than $1/2$ there is at least one bin with $2$ balls, i.e.** $\mathbb{P}(X = 0) \leq 1/2$.

Here is where I am stuck. Inequalities like Markov's and Chebyshev don't help to get this bound. How can I proceed from here?

Comment: Fixed, thank you

Comment: with your vector of probabilities $\mathbf p$ the formula is, the probability of at least 1 collision after $k$ balls / people is given by $1 - k!\cdot e_k\big(\mathbf p\big)$ where $e_k$ is the kth elementary symmetric function.  You can show that your problem, the inhomogenous birthday problem is $\geq $ probability of a collision in the homogenous case (where each $p_i$ is identical / uniform probability).  The uniform case is amenable to a poisson approximation... compute that m for the uniform case, and start shrinking $m$ for your inhomogenous case

Comment: @user8675309 that is a great idea. For the probability of at least $1$ collision, why is there a factor of $k!$? I think $1 - e_k(\mathbf{p})$ is the correct value.

Comment: Oh the factor of $k!$ is to account for the different order in which the balls can land in the same set of bins.

Comment: it's probably best viewed that way or just as a normalizing constant of some kind.  e.g. in the classical homogenous birthday problem the exact probability of *no collision* (i.e. the complementary probability) for k = 4 is $\big(1-\frac{0}{365}\big)\big(1-\frac{1}{365}\big)\big(1-\frac{2}{365}\big)\big(1-\frac{3}{365}\big)  =4! \cdot \binom{365}{4}\big(\frac{1}{365}\big)^4 = 4! e_4\big(\mathbf p\big)$ again in the special case of $\mathbf p := \frac{1}{365}\mathbf 1$

Answer (score 0):

You can recast the solution to the birthday problem, which is the same as yours except the probabilities of all the bins are equal, as saying each pair is an independent trial.  Taking that view, the chance of two balls not being in the same bin is $1-p$.   The chance that no pair is in the same bin is $(1-p)^{m/2}$.  You want 
$$(1-p)^{m \choose 2}\lt \frac 12\\
{m \choose 2}\log_2(1-p) \lt -1\\
\frac 12m(m-1)\gt \frac 1{\log_2(1-p)}$$
which is a quadratic you can feed to the quadratic formula

Comment: Aren't the pairs dependent, because $P(X_{ij}=1 \text{ and } X_{jk}=1) = \sum_{i} p_i^3 \neq P(X_{ij}=1) \cdot P(X_{jk}=1)$. Although intuitively I feel that the pairs should be independent, because knowing that balls $i$ and $j$ are in the same bin doesn't tell me anything about whether $j$ and $k$ are in the same bin.

Comment: When the $p_i$ are all equal to $1/n$ I think the pairs are pairwise independent but not three-way independent so this does not work I think.